# Oracle SQL Case with Null

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have a simple query that is taking an input from a bind variable.

```
CREATE TABLE "FRUITS" 
(   "FRUIT_NAME" VARCHAR2(100), 
"COLOR" VARCHAR2(100)
) ;

insert into fruits (fruit_name, color)
values ('Banana', 'Yellow')
insert into fruits (fruit_name, color)
values ('Lemon', '')
insert into fruits (fruit_name, color)
values ('Apple', 'Red')

SELECT * FROM FRUITS
WHERE
COLOR =     case
            when :P1_ITEM is null then null
            else :P1_ITEM
            end
```

If the input is 'Yellow' the result would be 'Banana' (when 'Red' then 'Apple'). However, if the input happens to be null the result is 'no data found'.
How can this be avoided knowing that null is not a null value?
If the input is null on color then how can I return the null color row? meaning 'Lemon' + null

Thanks

Comment: The result of any comparison with null will never be true in SQL

Comment: I don't think so, @GMB, because if P1_ITEM is NULL, query won't return anything because nothing is *equal to* NULL; should then be COLOR IS NULL.

Comment: Just don't use `case` expressions to build conditions based on other conditions. Use explicit boolean logic with `AND/OR`.  `where color = :p1_item or (:p1_item is null and color is null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be one option:

```
SELECT * FROM FRUITS
WHERE
nvl(COLOR, 'x') = case
                    when :P1_ITEM is null then 'x'
                    else :P1_ITEM
                  end;
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you Littlefoot